# Bloomberg API for python tutorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, bloomberg, blpapi

Does anyone know any good resources/ tutorials/ books to get started with Bloomberg's API blpapi in python?

I have searched everywhere and I haven't found anything at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you download the API from [the official website](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/) and you the zip file, you will find an "examples" folder which has plenty of examples.

Then there's the core developer guide if you need help on the schemas.

Comment: Would you happen to know where the schemas guide is? In the core developers guide there is a reference `For additional information, refer to the "Reference Services and Schemas Guide"` however I have be unable to find this? I have found a document referencing the schemas however this is somewhat old https://data.bloomberglp.com/labs/sites/2/2014/07/blpapi-developers-guide-2.54.pdf

Comment: It is available in WAPI <Go> then click on API Developers Guide and the document is in  the list.

Answer (score 1):

`xbbg` is a library with minimum setup and some relatively powerful functionalities:

https://xbbg.readthedocs.io/

For example this is how to download historical intraday data:

```
from xbbg import blp

blp.bdib('AAPL US Equity', '2018-11-21')
```

Comment: looks good but subscription api doesn't seem to be documented.